# Add User full_name in list_filter admin site

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I can't figure out how to add the User full_name in the list_filter.

My Blog model is as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils import timezone


class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Post(models.Model):
    POST_STATUS = (('borrador', 'Borrador'), ('publicado', 'Publicado'))

    title = models.CharField('titulo', max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField('cuerpo')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts', verbose_name='autor')
    created = models.DateTimeField('creado', auto_now_add=True)
    published = models.DateTimeField('publicado', auto_now=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField('actualizado', auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique_for_date='published')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=POST_STATUS, default='borrador')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-published',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

As you can see, I have created a custom user model just in case I have to change it in the future.
In the Blog model, there is a 'author' field which uses the User as FK.

I want to add the posibility to filter by 'author' in the Blog's admin site. To do this I tried the following:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User, Post

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)

@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'author', 'status', 'published')
    list_filter = ('author' , 'status', 'published')
    search_fields = [('title',), ('body',)]
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
    raw_id_fields = ('author',) # Reemplaza el drop-down para que parezca una lupa (para FKs)
    date_hierarchy = 'published'
    ordering = ('status', 'published')
```

The problem is that the filter by 'author' doesn't appear in the admin site:
[image]

If I do this: `list_filter = ('author__last_name' , 'status', 'published')` the filter shows up, but it looks like this ('appellido' means last_name in Spanish:

[image]

I would like the filter's text to be 'por autor (by author)' and be able to filter by the author's full name.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can do that with [**`django.contrib.admin.SimpleListFilter`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter):

```
from datetime import date

from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class PerAuthorListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('Per Author')
    parameter_name = 'per_author'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        authors = []
        for u in User.objects.all():
           authors.append((u.pk, '{} {}'.format(u.first_name, u.last_name)))

        return authors

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        queryset = super().queryset(request, queryset)
        return queryset.filter(author=self.value())

@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = [PerAuthorListFilter, ...]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had to remove `queryset = super().queryset(request, queryset)`, otherwise, an error was raised: "subclasses of ListFilter must provide a queryset() method". The problem is that the filter shows up excellent, but it is not filtering Users. I mean the result of the filter is empty (no posts' rows are shown). Any idea?

Comment: Okay, i will try to debug it.

Comment: Doing something like this gives me this error: `: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[1]' refers to 'FieldListFilter', which does not refer to a Field.` I did remember to import SimpleListFilter. Is there something else I need to do to make this work?

Comment: OK, I got it to understand my `FieldListFilter` and fixed that error. Now I'm getting a weirder one.

```NotImplementedError at /admin/intake/client/
subclasses of ListFilter must provide a queryset() method```

But it looks like `queryset` is right there. What have I done??